SQL Joining on multiple dates
I have table A and table B that I am trying to match on currency and dates. When it comes to the date, I want to match A and B only on the same date and if that doesn't work then a day later.
Table A
       DateA      CurrencyA   ID
    2021-12-31        GBP     1
    2022-01-01        GBP     2
    2022-01-02        GBP     3

Table B
       DateB      CurrencyB   
    2022-01-01        GBP         
    2022-01-02        GBP

This desired result of this join should result in
    ID     DateA      DateB       CurrrencyC 
    1    2021-12-31   2022-01-01     GBP
    2    2022-01-01   2022-01-01     GBP
    3    2022-01-02   2022-01-02     GBP

Current result is
   ID     DateA      DateB       CurrrencyC 
    1    2021-12-31   2022-01-01     GBP
    2    2022-01-01   2022-01-01     GBP
    2    2022-01-01   2022-01-02     GBP
    3    2022-01-02   2022-01-02     GBP

My current code -
SELECT *
FROM tableA t1
LEFT JOIN tableB t2 ON 
    (t1.date_column = t2.date_column)
    OR 
    (t1.date_column = DATEADD(day, -1, t2.date_column) AND t1.date_column NOT IN (SELECT date_column FROM tableA WHERE date_column = t2.date_column))

My current code is currently matching on multiple days. How do I fix it?

Why does tableB contain the same row twice? This doesn't seem to make much sense and makes joining more difficult.

For each tableA row you want to find the best tableB row. This is most easily done with a lateral join:
SELECT *
FROM tableA t1
OUTER APPLY 
(
  SELECT TOP(1) *
  FROM tableB t2
  WHERE t2.CurrencyB = t1.CurrencyA
  AND t2.DateB IN (t1.DateA, DATEADD(DAY, 1, t1.DateA))
  ORDER BY t2.DateB
) best_t2
ORDER BY t1.DateA;

